# Is there a way to change the backbone of Detectron2 keypoint detection model with custom object detection model?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, object-detection, faster-rcnn

I am working on a task where I have to detect people and do activity recognition. I am using **Detectron2 ****Keypoint detection** model.There are many False negatives with the detection. So my solution to reduce the FN's is to train the **custom detection** part of Detectron2 . I trained the custom detection model and got the improved results. But now I have to change the backbone of the Detectron2 object detection part with my custom detection model.

I changed the config file but that didn't work.